# MySQL Query to count number of records 2 layers deep in Query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables I am working with currently.  A table of customers and a table of payday loans they have.

The query I wrote that needs to get the amount of customers with outstanding loans is as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblcustomer
 WHERE pkcustomerid IN
     (SELECT fkcustomerid
     FROM
        (SELECT * FROM tblloan
        WHERE outstandingcurrentamount!="NULL") AS T)
```

This returns a list of customer data if they have a outstanding amount that is not NULL or 0.  Now I need to loop this result and execute individual queries on each customer to get all their loans.  But I just need the count.

Is there a way to somehow add an extra column to the data returned from the query that is a count of the loans for that customer?

Relevant parts of the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblcustomer` (
  `pkcustomerid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fkuserid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkstoreid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkcompanyid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkstaticid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   ...snip...
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkcustomerid`,`fkcountryid`,`fkcityid`,`fkstateid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=821 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblloan` (
  `pkloanid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fkuserid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkcustomerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fkstoreid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outstandingcurrentamount` double NOT NULL
  ...snip...
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkloanid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1567 ;
```

Comment: You aren't actually storing the keyword `NULL` as a string in that column `outstandingcurrentamount` (which otherwise would be numeric?), are you?

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements for each of those 2 tables.

Comment: no its the default NULL assigned by the DB.  but for some reason doing outstandingcurrentamount>=0   returns all records

Comment: Use `outstandingcurrentamount IS NOT NULL AND outstandingcurrentamount > 0` to properly test for non-null, nonzero rows

Comment: create table  http://privatepaste.com/9395ea199c.   wow lol. must be 4pm forgot its '>'  NOT '>='

Comment: the primary key "PRIMARY KEY (`pkcustomerid`,`fkcountryid`,`fkcityid`,`fkstateid`)" looks odd, why is there more columns after the auto_increment column?

Comment: I did not design these tables,  new on the project. So really no idea o.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t.*, q.loan_count 
  FROM tblcustomer t JOIN 
(
 SELECT c.pkcustomerid, COUNT(*) loan_count 
   FROM tblcustomer c LEFT JOIN  tblloan l 
     ON c.pkcustomerid = l. fkcustomerid
  WHERE l.outstandingcurrentamount IS NOT NULL 
    AND l.outstandingcurrentamount > 0
  GROUP BY c.pkcustomerid
) q ON t.pkcustomerid = q.pkcustomerid
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of the subquery? why not just run the subquery and select the wanted columns from it?

Comment: @PugganSe The purpose is to have all columns from `tblcustomer` that are not part of the `GROUP BY`, which is not allowed by "normal" RDBMSes (Oracle, SQL Server). Although it's allowed in MySql it's not a good idea since in theory there is no way to tell which value in the group to fetch for every such column. The other way is to use an aggregate function `MIN(), MAX()...` on such columns.

Comment: Thanks for the information, only use mysql myself, and therefor only know what mysql can, but its always nice to learn more about the others

Answer (score 1):

By using JOIN instead of subqueries, you can select stuff from all tables,
then use `GROUP BY` to get one row per customer, and use `COUNT(*)` to count the total number of combinations for that row = number of loans

```
SELECT COUNT(*), tblcustomer.*
FROM tblloan 
LEFT JOIN tblcustomer ON (tblloan.fkcustomerid = tblcustomer.pkcustomerid) 
WHERE tblloan.outstandingcurrentamount IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tblcustomer.pkcustomerid;
```

Comment: syntax error on (sorry I dont know mysql sytax the best).  LEFT JOIN ON (tblloan.fkcustomerid = tblcustomer.pkcustomerid)

Comment: Sorry, the table name should be before on